# Creating a 2D array based upon a CSV

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, matrix

I have a CSV file with millions of lines in the format of the below:

```
start, finish,count;
101,101,10;
101,103,2;
101,104,8;
102,103,5;
```

So we have a start location, an end location and a count of the number of people who make that journey.

What I'd like to do is put this into a 'table-style' matrix with all the start locations running along the top, all the end locations running down the side and in the body of the matrix have a sum of all the counts that sit within that intersect.

So far I have the CSV file cleaned and imported and have the start and end locations stored as vectors, however I'm unsure how to proceed when forming the body of the matrix, can anyone help?

Thank you.

EDIT: I would like it to look as follows:

```
    101,102;
101,10,0;
103,2,5;
104,8,0;
```

Comment: Can you please provide some sample output?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the same (source, destination) pair might be repeated, or will there always be at most a single count for a given source and destination?

Comment: Hi @GauravDhama I've added this into the question.

Comment: Hi @holdenweb , there will be multiple entries with the same source & destination, hence the need to sum all the counts within the matrix body.

Answer (score 2):

use `set_index` and `unstack`

```
df.set_index(['start', 'finish'])['count'].unstack(0)
```

[image]

---

To save to csv

```
print df.set_index(['start', 'finish'])['count'].unstack(0).rename_axis(None) \
    .to_csv('myfilename.csv')

,101,102
101,10.0,
103,2.0,5.0
104,8.0,
```

Comment: That's fantastic @piRSqaured, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: If this answered your question, don't forget to check it.

Answer (score 0):

You said you have millions of lines, so i don't know whether this will be effective or not, but if you don't run into memory issues a pandas dataframe is the way to go:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('inputfile.csv')

df = df.groupby(['start','finish']).agg({'count':sum}).reset_index()
# Create Pivot table
df_out = df.pivot(index='finish',columns = 'start',values='count')
# Write Output
df_out.rename_axis(None).to_csv('output.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks for that @GauravDhama, the only problem is that I was hoping to have all the unique 'start' values running across the top of the table and all the unique 'end' values running down the side of the table. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Have edited the program. Check if this works for you!!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
print (df.pivot(index='finish', columns='start', values='count'))
start    101  102
finish           
101     10.0  NaN
103      2.0  5.0
104      8.0  NaN
```

If need remove columns and index names use [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
print (df.pivot(index='finish', columns='start', values='count')
         .rename_axis(None)
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
      101  102
101  10.0  NaN
103   2.0  5.0
104   8.0  NaN
```